# Access denied error in code when using Impersonation

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are using Active Directory groups to give access to a SharePoint site by adding Active Directory groups to the SharePoint groups. This way, users present in Active Directory groups are easily able to access the SharePoint site and business users can easily manage user access by just managing Active directories.

However, code which uses impersonation to access/update SharePoint objects (list/library) is getting Access denied error.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Here is a trimmed down version of the code for simplicity -

```
public static SPUser GetClaimParameterValue(string identity, SPWeb web)
{            
    SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName, identity, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Forms, "custom-id-provider"));
    userName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);
    user = web.EnsureUser(userName); 
    return user;
}

public static SPWeb GetImpersonatedWeb(SPWeb objWeb, string site, string userId, string user)
{
    SPUser spUser = FetchUserDetail.GetClaimParameterValue(userId, objWeb);
    SPUserToken oUserToken = spUser.UserToken;
    SPWeb impWeb;
    using (SPSite impSite = new SPSite(site, oUserToken))
    {
        impWeb = impSite.OpenWeb();
    }
    return impWeb;
}

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionURL))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        // userId = User’s Email                        
        SPWeb impersonatedWeb = BusinessLayer.GetImpersonatedWeb(oWeb, siteCollectionURL, userId, user);

        SPListItem oListItem = impersonatedWeb.GetListItem(relativeURL);//Access Denied error in this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One big problem in ypur code is that you continue using a SharePoint object after it's been disposed:

In `GetImpersonatedWeb`, you open `impSite` with the user's token, you then open `impWeb` and finaly you close `impSite` just before returning `impWeb`.
The caller then uses `impWeb` while its parent `SPSite` (`impSite`) had been disposed.
(note: call to `.Dispose` is implicit with the `using` structure)

To me, the correct version would read:

```
public static SPUser GetClaimParameterValue(string identity, SPWeb web)
{            
    SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName, identity, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Forms, "custom-id-provider"));
    userName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);
    user = web.EnsureUser(userName); 
    return user;
}

public static SPSite GetImpersonatedSite(SPWeb objWeb, string userId)
{
    SPUser spUser = FetchUserDetail.GetClaimParameterValue(userId, objWeb);
    SPUserToken oUserToken = spUser.UserToken;
    SPSite impSite = new SPSite(objWeb.Url, oUserToken)
    return impSite;
}


//USAGE
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionURL))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        // userId = User’s Email
        using(SPSite impersonatedSite = BusinessLayer.GetImpersonatedSite(oWeb, userId))
        {
             using(SPWeb impersonatedWeb = impersonatedSite.OpenWeb())
             {    
                  SPListItem oListItem = impersonatedWeb.GetListItem(relativeURL);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Evariste. Thanks for the tip. We tried following your approach which actually makes a lot of sense. However it did not helped. Please let me know if you can think of anything else which can help in resolving this issue.

Comment: One thing bothers me: why do you open a new `oSite` object at all? Why don't you use the current (contextual, i.e. `SPContext.Current.Web`) object instead... that would increase performances. And this new fresh `SPSite` object, based on `siteCollectionURL` makes me think: is this site hosted in the same Web app the code actually runs in? This is a prerequisite of using impersonated SP objects.

Comment: Actually, we are running this code in a web-service deployed on the SharePoint server. So the web-service is not able to get current context using SPContext.Current.Web.

Comment: It depends, it could... for instance if it's hosted in a subfolder of _layouts... What's the Web application/App pool (in an IIS sense) it runs under?

Comment: The web-service is hosted in separate web-site in IIS. However we have ensured that its App-Pool is same as the App-Pool of our SharePoint web-application (IIS website).